# Adding columns to devise Users table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a devise Users Model

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    ...
  end
end
```

I want to add these columns to the model. I think I might be confusing myself with the automatic pluralize that Rails does.

When I use the command `rails g migration AddDetailsToUsers` and I added following code inside the `change` method.

```
class AddDetailsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :Users, :username,           :string
    add_column :Users, :firstname,          :string
    add_column :Users, :lastname,           :string
    add_column :Users, :billing_address,    :string
    add_column :Users, :credit_card,            :string
    add_column :Users, :total_earned,           :string
    add_column :Users, :home_address, :string
    add_column :Users, :leeway_time, :string
  end
ends
```

I did `rake db:migrate` to try to update the DB, I get

```
== 20141012065730 AddDetailsToUsers: migrating ================================
-- add_column(:Users, :username, :string)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "Users" does not exist
```

I try to see if I can play with this table in `rails c

```
 User.first
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Table name is case sensitive. Change all occurrences of `:Users` to `:users` in the migration file

eg:

```
add_column :users, :username, :string
add_column :users, :firstname, :string
..
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The command got further than before but now this error is showing NameError: uninitialized constant AddDetailsToUserup ``

Comment: There could be a typo. Could you show the changed migration file?

Comment: Did you change the name of the file? It should be `db/migrate/XXXXXXXXXXXXX_add_details_to_users.rb` where XXXXXXX is a timestamp. From the error message it sounds like you've renamed the file to `db/migrate/XXXXXXXXXXXXX_add_details_to_userup.rb`.